# Read only <input> prevents adding value to different element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a series of `<input>` elements and a corresponding script that auto focuses the next box after typing.  In addition there is a readonly element that there purely to provide context to the user.

The readonly element prevents typing a value in `#DialFifth`.  I've attempted to use attribute selectors to prevent picking up elements with readonly but this doesn't seem to work.

Please see the snippet - any ideas?

```js
$(':input').keypress(function() {
  $(this).next(':input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="DialFirst" name="DialFirst" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialSecond" name="DialSecond" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialThird" name="DialThird" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFourth" name="DialFourth" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFifth" name="DialFifth" type="text" value="" /> <!--Unable to type into this box-->
<input id="DialFinal" name="DialFinal" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is to do with the order in which the value is changed and the event is fired. To do what you require, use `keyup` instead:

```js
$(':input').keyup(function() {
    $(this).next(':input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="DialFirst" name="DialFirst" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialSecond" name="DialSecond" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialThird" name="DialThird" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFourth" name="DialFourth" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFifth" name="DialFifth" type="text" value="" />
<input id="DialFinal" name="DialFinal" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="0" />
```

Comment: Thanks - had an inkling this was something order related

Comment: No problem, glad to help.